# The necessity of ground state in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, second-quantization, unitarity

Why we always want to have a ground state in every physical theory?

For example, when we try to quantize Dirac Hamiltonian and encounter a Hamiltonian without a ground state, we take a step back and choose anti commutation relations.
 The Hamiltonian is $\hat H=\sum (\hat N_b-\hat N_a)$ when $\hat N$ are the number operators correspond to the particle and anti particle.

Why having energy bounded from below is so important physically? 
(In gravity we have negative unbounded energy and it doesn't seem to bother).

Comment: "In gravity we have negative unbounded energy and it doesn't seem to bother"  ?? quantized gravity??

Comment: A problem with energies that are not bounded from below is the question about semi-classical stability of vacua. How could we tell if a critical point won't decay to lower energy states if we don't have a minimized functional that we can associate with energy in the classical limit. This is an important field of study in quantum gravity.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "existence and uniqueness of the vacuum" is independent from whether the Hamiltonian in unbounded from below or not. Which of these statements are you asking about?